# How to import photos to SDcard folder of the emulator

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am developing an application for photo galleries. While testing it on phone it works fine but to test it on Emulator it requires photos on SDCard of the emulator.
So please tell me how to add photos on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse, 1) Start the Emulator 2)Select DDMS-> Select your emulator-> File Explorer -> mnt -> sdcard then select push button on header and push your file in android emulator.